# Software Security Center Demo install is not showing two mennus in the dashboard?

Tags: security, fortify

I have installed the demo version of HP Software security centre. I can only see dashboard and administration mennu in software security centre. I have checked all the options but still couldn't figured it out what step i am missing ?

Its not the original installation, its the demo version ? due to some scenario i am in need of this version.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ163.png)

## Logs

[3784 2016-02-21T11:31:39.958+0500 INFO] built event handler chain of length 29
[3784 2016-02-21T11:31:40.224+0500 ERROR] License does not include Runtime.  File: C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_Demonstration_Suite_4.10\java_runtime\internal\remote_config\localhost\default_federation\demo-config\fortify.license
[3784 2016-02-21T11:31:40.313+0500 ERROR] License does not include Runtime.  File: C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_Demonstration_Suite_4.10\fortify.license
[3784 2016-02-21T11:31:40.385+0500 ERROR] License does not include Runtime.  File: C:\fortify.license
[3784 2016-02-21T11:31:40.415+0500 FATAL] Fortify runtime encountered a fatal error: License check failed
[3784 2016-02-21T11:31:40.426+0500 FATAL] Terminating without executing main program because of fatal error. Set environment variable FORTIFY_CONTINUE_ON_STARTUP_ERROR to run without Fortify.

## [3784 2016-02-21T11:31:40.437+0500 INFO] Fortify Runtime shutting down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log shows that either

1. Your license is expired
2. Or the license you are using do not provide facility of supporting
   SSC.
   Change the license and it will surely work